# How to achieve the text before Rect in PDF file in pymupdf

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, automation, mupdf

I'm trying to achieve the coordinates where  "______" is present. Which I am easily be able to achieve using the MuPDF. After getting this Rect Coordinates I need to get the string or character before this Rect coordinates.

My main objective is to read the PDF file and wherever there is user input I need to draw rectangle there and get what data to be filled in that user input.

I hope I sounds clear.

Please have a look on my code which i have done till now.

```
import fitz

file = "real.pdf"

doc = fitz.open(file)

def searchTextAndHighLight(page):
  text = "_"
  text_instances = page.searchFor(text)
  i = 0
  for inst in text_instances:
    print(inst)
    print("<----------------------------------------->")
    i+=1
    highlight = page.addRectAnnot(inst)
  print(i)
  doc.save("output.pdf", garbage=4, deflate=True, clean=True)

  for page in doc:
    searchTextAndHighLight(page)
```

Any suggestion are most welcome to achieve my task. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem like you. Try this. It works for me.

```
import fitz

file = "real.pdf"

doc = fitz.open(file)

def searchTextAndHighLight(page):
  text = "_"
  text_instances = page.searchFor(text)
  i = 0
  for inst in text_instances:
    print(inst)
    print("<----------------------------------------->")
    i+=1
    highlight = page.addRectAnnot(inst)
    highlight.setBlendMode(fitz.PDF_BM_Multiply)
    highlight.update()
  print(i)
  doc.save("output.pdf", garbage=4, deflate=True, clean=True)

for page in doc:
  searchTextAndHighLight(page)
```